# CSS transform-origin not working for svg in safari

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, safari

I am trying to rotate the image about its center. But in Safari, the top left corner of the SVG, it's origin is always taken as the center for rotation.

```
       var rotate_val= 30;
       function rotate(val){
           rotate_val =  rotate_val + val;
           var transform = "translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1) rotate("+rotate_val+ ")";

           var svg = d3.select("g").transition()
            .style('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%')
            .style('transform-origin', 'center')
            .duration(1200)
            .attrTween("transform",function(interpolate) {
                return d3.interpolate(transform, transform);
            });

       }



  <body>
      <button onclick="rotate(30)">Rotate + 30</button>
      <button onclick="rotate(-30)">Rotate - 30</button>
      <div id = "svgcontainer" style="border: 1px solid">
         <svg width = "100%" height = "100%" viewBox="0 0 750 400">
             <g>
                 <image x="325" y="150" xlink:href="image.png" height="100" width="100"/>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ztw2omgb/

Comment: Here is the code 
https://jsfiddle.net/ztw2omgb/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs for transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), the status of `transform-origin` for `SVG` is *Compatibility Unknown*. So it may not be implemented yet in Safari.

*However*, if you remove the `transform-origin` attributes completely, you can use the second and third arguments of the `rotate()` function to define the center of rotation for your selected element. e.g.

Your image's `x`, and `y` values are *325* and *150* respectively, and the width and height are both 100. So the center of rotation should be the `x` and `y` values plus half the width and height (50) giving *375* and *200*.

```
function rotate(val){
  rotate_val =  rotate_val + val;

  // note the rotate function now contains second and third argument,
  // which specify the center of rotation.
  var transform = "translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1) rotate("+rotate_val+ ", 375, 200)";

  d3.select("g").transition()
    .duration(1200)
    .attrTween("transform",function(interpolate) {
       return d3.interpolate(transform, transform);
    });

}
```

Comment: They actually do support it... for transformations applied through CSS..